# How does gentle boosting differ from AdaBoost?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting

There is a variant of boosting called [gentleboost](http://dx.doi.org/10.1214/aos/1016218223).  How does gentle boosting differ from the better-known [AdaBoost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost)?

Comment: What other variants?  It might be helpful to tighten up this question a little (more specificity).

Comment: Right; it is just one variant among others.

Comment: OK, I'll ask for comparison to adaboost since that is perhaps the best known.

Answer (score 6):

The second paper you cite seems to contain the answer to your question. To recap; mathematically, the main difference is in the shape of the loss function being used. Friedman, Hastie, and Tibshirani's loss function being easier to optimize at each iteration. –